# Copy image from Google Sheets to Google Docs using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I was working on generating a report as Google Docs document using data from spreadsheets. Some parts of the sheets contain a step-by-step screenshot walkthrough (That is, text, image, text, image vertically). That needs to be copied to the doc.

I have read through Google Apps Script reference and found that `OverGridImage` represent the image in the file. However, there was no method that allows exporting as a blob, or even a URL. (Since the image pasted on the sheets come directly from clipboard, there is no URL of the image in the first place, so `getUrl()` does not work.)

Is there any workaround that is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid what you're trying to do is currently **not possible**.

The class [OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image) was released fairly recently ([October 2018](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2018#october_30_2018)) and, as you said, there is no way to retrieve the Blob for such images. There is actually an **[open Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119800855) in Issue Tracker** regarding this.

Since there is no [BlobSource interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source) related to this class, there is no way to get a reference of that image, if you have no URL. And the image cannot be retrieved by Sheets API either.

#### Reference:

- [OverGridImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image)
- [Feature Request: Update OverGridImage to support BlobSource interface](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119800855)

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation. Sadly, there is no way to implement this. I will continue trying to find a workaround.

Comment: @Bearfinn You're welcome. The workarounds I can think of are related to adding the image from an URL or from Drive. If you just upload it from your device, I'm afraid there is nothing that can be done. Also, remember that you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answers that you consider helpful. This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The thing is that the client would like it to be easy to paste the images, such as pasting them directly in the sheet. I think they would have to do the upload and copy the link themselves. Also, thank you for your suggestion. I have accepted your answer!

Comment: Have you checked out this library: https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp?
Although the library has some issues but it is able to retrieve overgridimages as well as in-cell-images. How does it manage to do that?