# How can I save an OverGridImage to a file on Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script

In GoogleAppsScript, I have an OverGridImage that I want to save to a file (in Google Drive), as a .jpg file.  If I had a Blob it would be fairly straightforward.  So another way to word the question is perhaps "how to convert an OverGridImage to a Blob?".

Comment: It appears from this thread that what I am trying to do is not possible.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409730/copy-image-from-google-sheets-to-google-docs-using-google-apps-script
Does anyone know if this has changed?