# How to insert images to a Google Document using AppScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that creates a document during runtime and attach it to a variable.

I need to insert images to it using a script.

Here is my code:

```
  var modulo = "foo";
  var nomeDoc = "bar";
  let doc =  DocumentApp.create("Validação escopo ("+ modulo +") cliente: " + nomeDoc);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var imgPDF = body.appendImage(blob);
```

How do i pass an image as "blob" inside the variable: `imgPDF`?

**Important: The image is in the Spreadsheet that calls this function.**

Comment: Is that the entire code? What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Unless thing have changed since this article its not possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409730/copy-image-from-google-sheets-to-google-docs-using-google-apps-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On January 19, 2022, 2 Classes for using the inner cell image were added to the Spreadsheet service. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#january_19_2022) But, in the current stage, the image can be put into a cell. But, unfortunately, the image in the cell cannot be retrieved. I think that this might be a bug. And also, these Classes cannot retrieve the images on a cell as the blob and the image URL. I think that this is the specification.

So, as the current workaround, I thought that in your situation, in the current stage, this method can be used. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040243/7108653)

In this workaround, a Google Apps Script library might be able to be used. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp) This library can retrieve both the image in a cell and the image on a cell.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

You can see the method for installing this library at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp#how-to-install).

#### 2. Enable Drive API.

In this case, Drive API is used. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

#### 3. Sample script.

```
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Google Spreadsheet ID
const res = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName("Sheet1").getImages();
console.log(res); // You can check the retrieved images at the log.
if (res.length == 0) return;
const blob = res[0].image.blob; // Here, 1st image of Sheet1 is retrieved. Of course, you can choose the image on the sheet.

let doc = DocumentApp.create("Validação escopo (" + modulo + ") cliente: " + nomeDoc);
var body = doc.getBody();
var imgPDF = body.appendImage(blob);
```

- In this case, please declare `modulo` and `nomeDoc`.

#### 4. Testing.

When the above script is run, the images are retrieved from "Sheet1" and put the 1st image to the created Document body.

### References:

- [DocsServiceApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp)
- Related thread

  - [How to access new 'in-cell-image' from google apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56733340/7108653)

Comment: Thanks.  I learned something new today.  Will learning never stop.